Parsing and working with microsecond-precision timestamps in R using dplyr
I'm planning to collect data with microsecond-precision timestamps in the format "DD/MM/YY  HH:MM:SS.mmmuuun"? How would I parse in R and keep working in a dplyr pipeline?
Example:
"26/09/24 11a:16:36.5933210"

df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 1),
  Timestamp = c("26/09/24 11a:16:36.5933210",
                "26/09/24 11a:16:36.6518648",
                "26/09/24 11p:16:36.7280308"),
  CH = c(11, 11, 11)
)

I would still like to retain the date and time information for later correlation with observations. Note "a" for am and "p" for pm.

Do these answers help?

Why is there a single a after the 11 hour - is that an am/pm indicator?

Yes a for am and p for pm (will update) - this pretty get it without losing too much precision: str_replace("26/09/24 11a:16:36.5933210", "a:", ":") |> parse_date_time("d/m/y H:M:OS", tz = "UTC")

Are you sure that is doing the hours calculation correctly? The H/%H format is usually for 24 hour time - you'd want %I for 12 hour and %p for the am/pm indicator I think.

Yes correct, just checked the raw data and there are timestamps: "26/09/24 09p:52:44.4914233"

Using dmy_hms with AM/PM moved to the end of the string.
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Timestamp_new = dmy_hms(sub("( \\d{2})([ap])(.*$)", "\\1\\3 \\2m", Timestamp)),
         ms = format(Timestamp_new, "%OS3"))
  ID                  Timestamp CH       Timestamp_new     ms
1  1 26/09/24 11a:16:36.5933210 11 2024-09-26 11:16:36 36.593
2  1 26/09/24 11a:16:36.6518648 11 2024-09-26 11:16:36 36.651
3  1 26/09/24 11a:16:36.7280308 11 2024-09-26 11:16:36 36.728

Note you can use up to n <= 6 in %OSn. Also using as.POSIXct with format="%d/%m/%y %I:%M:%OS %p") will work too. Thanks @thelatemail  for pointing out the right format.

%OS3 is not used on input and will result in an NA. It is just %OS as per ?strptime - "'%OS' will input seconds including fractional seconds." You'd also have to have the %p included somewhere in the as.POSIXct call. E.g. x <- "26/09/24 3p:16:36.5933210"; as.POSIXct(sub("([ap])", "\\1m", x), format="%d/%m/%y %I%p:%M:%OS")

Thanks and seems to work! Covers both am and pm timestamps

@thelatemail I m going to leave out the as.POSIXct part. It does not generate NA for me if I use n. Also somehow the %p doesn't work for me.

@thelatemail Ah, dummy me, I forgot the format= argument name. That messed up the output.

I thought times were only accurate to milliseconds?

@IRTFM ?strptime says for output gives the seconds truncated to 0 <= n <= 6 decimal places …
